# Amplifier transistors not receiving change in base voltage... do I look forwards or backwards?

Tags: transistors, oscilloscope, crt

So I'm working on diagnosing a CRT scope that isn't responding to the horizontal controls; the trace is off screen. The two X plates are each being driven by 2 transistors in line. One X plate has over 100V going to it, and its transistors' base voltages are changing in sync with the horizontal position pot as I turn it. However, the other X plate which has 0V on it, its transistors' emitters and collectors have a sporadic 2-3V jumping up and down, and its bases aren't responding to the horizontal position pot.

My gut tells me I need to look upstream of the transistor's base (the one not responding to the horizontal position pot.) Is this correct?

Or could the problem exist in the emitter/collector circuit somewhere, and be interfering with the base of the transistor?

I've got a diagram if you need one.

Thanks a heap!

Comment: This is back to the questions you've already posted with schematic diagrams?

Comment: @Jared - (a) "*I've got a diagram if you need one.*" Each question should be "standalone", so even if you have supplied the schematic in another question, yes, I recommend you add it here too. At the very least, that will allow you (and people writing answers) to refer to component designators like "Q123" (or whatever). (b) This question doesn't mention its relationship to your previous question(s). I recommend explaining how they are linked e.g. so that people don't waste time repeating things you have already learned from those previous Q&A.

Comment: Sam, this question is completely unrelated to my last. No information in the previous thread could could have answered this question. My previous question was about the purpose of transistors in the circuit, this question is explaining symptoms of the circuit, and asking what the next step in diagnosis should be based on those symptoms. I didn't post a diagram because I didn't want people to think I was continuing on my previous question, and also because I didn't think a question with such simple information would have needed a diagram for someone to know which direction I needed to look.

Comment: Jonk, I hoped I'd be able to get some diagnosis advice based on the symptoms of the circuit that I've presented without people thinking I'm asking the same thing that I was in my previous question. Yes, it is the same circuit, but this is a new topic. If I had continued bothering everyone on the previous thread, it would have been a "help me diagnose this faulty scope" thread that would have required hours of people's time. I didn't want to bother anybody like that.

Comment: @Jared  - Thanks for your reply. I respectfully disagree with some parts (e.g. your reasoning not to supply a circuit diagram), but it's your question not mine, and so I'll stop here. Sincere good luck with your troubleshooting.

Comment: I would love to post a diagram if you think it would be helpful, and to abide by y'all's suggestions, but it seems like nobody wanted to answer my question after it got the drive by treatment. Like it's doomed now or something.